# Using unwindSegue / array of dictionaries for quiz

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to make a quiz that I made more dynamic than what it is. Right now my app can only answer one question at a time because I used a switch thinking that I would be able to work with it. The problem that I have now, is that I can not run through an entire category of questions until it goes back to the category selection page.

Now I will say, I am new to programming and I have had a lot of help from this site in manipulating what I had into what it is now, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around this concept. I have a couple books from O'Reilly and Programming Objective C sixth edition and I came across Segues and UnwindSegue and think that this could be an answer for me. I don't however understand how to fully implement it the way that I want. I want to know how I can have the app ask a question, and immediately after answering the question display a correct/incorrect screen with the question and correct answer on the screen, and then proceed to the next question within the same category. Here is a sample of what I have for my question:

```
-(void)Category1{



    NSUInteger QuestionSelected= (arc4random() %100);

    switch (QuestionSelected) {
        case 0:

            QuestionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Here is Question 1"];
            [Answer1 setTitle:@"Possible Answer" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer2 setTitle:@"Possible Answer" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer3 setTitle:@"Possible Answer" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer4 setTitle:@"Possible Answer" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            Answer1Correct = YES;
            CorrectAnswerDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Correct Answer"];
            break;
        case 1:
            QuestionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Here is Question 2"];
            [Answer1 setTitle:@"Possible Answer" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer2 setTitle:@"Possible Answer" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer3 setTitle:@"Possible Answer" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer4 setTitle:@"Possible Answer" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            Answer1Correct = YES;
            CorrectAnswerDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Correct Answer"];
            break;
```

I did this with the original thought that I would be able to fall through the switch (I did not understand the fall through feature of a switch and after I did more research.. I am not really sure if I still do although I know it isn't the right way anymore though).

In the example that apple posted using UnwindSegue they used a .plist full of questions. If I were to use a plist along with segues to transition back and forth between my view controllers would I be able to have that correct/incorrect screen in between questions? Right now I have five categories and here is how my storyboard is set up:

Intoduction Controller > 
Nothing special for this one just a button to go to Categories

Category Selection screen >
Here it lists the Five separate categories to choose from

Question/Answer ViewController >

Here it has a label and four buttons to display whatever question/answers it pulls from the switch in addition to a different label to display the correct answer after a choice is selected and the buttons disappear.

So to reiterate the order in hope to be clear, right now I will select a category and it will bring me to my third ViewController. It will ask me a question and then display four possible answers to choose. I will select an answer and it will stay within the third view controller and display whether I am correct/incorrect, still display the question and show the correct answer. Then at the bottom I have a button to return to the categories page where I can choose the same category again.

I am trying to do this app solely to learn how utilize memory management with segues and to try to understand the dynamic side of development. I am not trying to just get the answer done for me, so if you are willing to explain the process a little bit I would really appreciate it or if I have some questions about the logic of what is happening please be gentle. Thanks everyone again for all the help. This site truly has been a blessing for me.

Edit: I apologize if I posted asking this question prematurely, but sometimes I guess you have to see it to figure it out. I think that using an NSDictionary would be the ideal way to do it. I am not quite familiar with using an array of dictionaries, but someone else here sent me:

```
- (void)categoryOne
{
    NSUInteger questionSelected = arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)self.arrayOfQuestions.count);

    NSDictionary *thisQuestion = self.arrayOfQuestions[questionSelected];

    [questionsLabel setText:thisQuestion[@"question"]];

    [answerOneButton setTitle:thisQuestion[@"answer1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [answerTwoButton setTitle:thisQuestion[@"answer2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [answerThreeButton setTitle:thisQuestion[@"answer3"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [answerFourButton setTitle:thisQuestion[@"answer4"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    answer1Correct = YES;
    correctAnswerDisplay.text = thisQuestion[@"answer"];
}
```

I am going to read up more on using arrays and see if I can make a little bit more sense of how to implement this and how it can relate to my quiz app. The more I keep going over these it makes a little bit more sense. This site really has done wonders, I just don't want to misunderstand and look like an idiot or someone asking for a handout.

Attached is some pictures of the question and answer screen I am trying to maintain.

[image: Question Page]

[image: Answer Page]

Comment: Do you even need to unwind segues ? Just present and pop the third view controller as required. The correct / incorrect part of the screen could be achieved with a UILabel.

Comment: I was thinking if I would input my info into a plist I could use unwind segues to pop back and forth between my controllers just like in this tut: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UnwindSegue/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html but using this method it just goes straight to the next question after answering. I know I am probably overlooking something, but I don't know how to use this method, but still keep the second screen that says whether it is correct or not before it continues to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly easy to achieve what you want. You need to focus on the didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the QuestionViewController :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    // This method is called regardless of the value returned by 
    // -shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:.  Therefore, check if this view
    // controller is displaying the final question and advance to the results
    // screen only if it is.
    if (indexPath.section == 1 && self.lastQuestion)
    {
        self.currentQuiz[self.questionIndex].selectedResponse = indexPath.row;

        // Trigger the segue leading to the results screen.
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ResultScreen" sender:self];
    }
}
```

When the user selects an answer you want to handle this by updating e.g a UILabel, instead of triggering the next segue. In short just remove the line [self performSegueWithIdentifier...] and put in some code to update the screen with correct or incorrect. When you are ready to go back to the previous screen then implement your rewind.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for answering! I am trying to understand what is going on. So I would make a plist with all my questions and answers in it. I understand that putting something that would trigger the correct/incorrect screen, but using this method it changes how I used that screen. I have never used a properties list before or table views, is there a way to pull the correct answer and input into a UIlabel? Right now I literally just added a NSstring and manually typed up every answer at the end of every switch. I am going to see if I can find somewhere to read more about plists

Comment: I am not sure if a tableview will run the app exactly how I want it to.. I am trying to keep the interface the same.. I just don't know the best way to use it. I am going to do a little more research and come back to this. Thank you so much for the help though.

Comment: I am reading up on using an array of dictionaries. I think that this may be a way I can pull off what I want. Hopefully this will lead me where I want. I would think this would be more common, but it has been kind of tough figuring this out. haha. I will post an update if I figure it out.